# First Byte greater than Start Render. Is this possbile?

Tags: performance, performance-testing, webpagetest

I have a private instance of WebPagetest. Sometimes I see that **First Byte** more than **Start Render** metric.  How is this possible? What should I investigate to verify that test is not bad?